# Is it possible to stop the recording manually by using voice RecognizerIntent in android?

Tags: android, voice-recognition

Right now i am working with voice recognizer in android using **RecognizerIntent**.
Here is my ambiguation,

After clicking the record button,because of using RecognizerIntent it showing one popup window with speech recorder.After speaking something to that it is automatically stopping that popup window, but i want to place one button called "**STOP**" to that popup windoe to stop the current recording manually.Is it possible to do with RecognizerIntent?

Suggestion please

thanks for your precious time!..

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

protected static final int RESULT_SPEECH = 1;

private ImageButton btnSpeak;
private TextView txtText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtText);

    btnSpeak = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

    btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");

            try {
                startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH);
                txtText.setText("");
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {

                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Ops! Your device doesn't support Speech to Text",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case RESULT_SPEECH: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            ArrayList<String> text = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

            txtText.setText(text.get(0));
        }
        break;
    }   }}}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to have full control over the UI implement it yourself (your current approach launches an external activity) and access the recognizer via [SpeechRecognizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html).